# How can you use a reverse iterator with an iterator that is a proxy

Tags: c++, iterator, reverse-iterator

Given you have an iterator that is effectively a proxy and contains the data that it returns, how can you make a reverse iterator?

std::reverse_iterator implementation of the dereferencing operator creates a temporary object which it then decrements and dereferences, with code that is something like:

```
  reference operator*() const {
    iterator tmp = current;
    return *--tmp;
  }
```

with the result that what it returns to you is a pointer to data that goes out of scope before you get hold of it.

This has rather unfortunate results.

How can you get round this?

Comment: Do you mean that your iterator owns object that it should return (isn't it opposite to a proxy)?

Comment: It's illegal to use `reverse_iterator` with a "proxy iterator" because it requires a bidirectional iterator, and their `operator*` has to return a `T cv&`.

Comment: @nikitoz The iterator I'm currently looking at was described as 'being like a proxy', so yes, it might not be a proxy. And yes, the dereference returns something that the iterator owns.

Comment: @Simple the iterator is bidirectional and the `operator*` returns a `T cv &`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you'll need to write your own custom reverse iterator implementation for this specific case since your iterator type is not compatible with this specific implementation of reverse_iterator.

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator, some implementations do also store a decremented copy of the iterator but not all.  Boost::reverse_iterator does not appear to store an additional copy.

Answer (score 1):

I think the standard library implementation is incorrect. If you look at 24.5.1.3.4 [reverse.iter.op.star] in the C++11 standard you'll find the following:

```
deref_tmp = current;
--deref_tmp;
return *deref_tmp;
```

> Note: This operation must use an auxillary member variable rather than a temporary variable to avoid returning a reference that persists beyond the lifetime of the associated iterator.

In the standard `deref_tmp` is a for-exposition-only data member of `reverse_iterator`.

Comment: I don't have a copy of the C++03 standard, but this might be a defect that was fixed in C++11.

Comment: C++03 has the wording `Iterator tmp = current; return *--tmp;` so this is compliant but wrong by the C++03 standard and fixed in C++11.